# Stratified sampling in Scala

Tags: scala, sampling, resampling

I'm trying to create the equivalent of the following stratified sampling in scala.

Python code which is working as expected

```
stratifiedDF = labeledAllDF.sampleBy('column', fractions={0: 0.2, 1: 1.0}).drop("column")
```

I tried the following code but running into issues

```
val fractions= Map(0->0.2,1->1)
val approxSample = indexedDS.rdd.sampleByKeyExact(withReplacement = true, fractions = fractions)
```

ERROR -

```
value sampleByKeyExact is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
```

The API on stratified sampling suggests that I can use sample on RDD but doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: That error means `sampleByKeyExact` is not a method in the `RDD` class. There is, however, a [`sample` method](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#sample(withReplacement:Boolean,fraction:Double,seed:Long):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T]) that looks very similar